Is this why a project can fail to compile if two headers include each other?
I'm trying to understand why two mutually included headers (each header including the other) doesn't work the way you might expect. I was wondering if my reasoning is correct:
If you have FooHeader.h:
#pragma once
#include "BarHeader.h"

struct Foo { Bar bar;};

And a BarHeader.h:
#pragma once
#include "FooHeader.h"
struct Bar { Foo foo; };

The reason why this might not compile is the following:
Say you have main.cpp that:
#include "BarHeader.h"

int main() { }

Now the preprocessor does it's job, replaces the "BarHeader.h" so that it looks like this:
|remove|
#include "BarHeader.h"

|add|
#include "FooHeader.h"
struct Bar { Foo foo; };

int main() {}

OK, that's step 1. But the preprocessor still has work to do, to substitute "FooHeader.h", so the next step is:
|remove|
#include "FooHeader.h"

|add|
#include "BarHeader.h"
struct Foo { Bar bar;}



struct Bar { Foo foo; }

int main() {}

Now the file looks like this:
#include "BarHeader.h"


struct Foo { Bar bar;}

struct Bar { Foo foo; }

int main() {}

It still has an include there, BUT, seeing as that header file has already been included, it doesn't include it again, so the end result is:
struct Foo { Bar bar;}
    
struct Bar { Foo foo; }
    
int main() {}

This is why there are compilation problems, right?
Wouldn't this be solved if the preprocessor simply moved the already included header to the point of the it's highest/first occurrence within the file? So something like "I see I have already included you, but you've been included up here, so I'll move it up here, and then things are fine."? That would solve the problem right?

There are cases where it is desirable to be able to include a file more than once, at different points in a file.  Your proposal would prevent that from working, if I understand correctly.  There are even cases where it is desirable to include a file recursively, though maybe dubious.

This also seems like a solution to a problem that doesn't really exist.  There is already a perfectly good way to deal with circular header inclusion, namely include guards.

There's also the bigger problem in your code that each struct type has a member of the other type, which is impossible.  That has nothing to do with how the header files are organized.  (Though it is possible to have two struct types, each of which has a member which is a pointer to the other type.)

@NateEldredge Wait, I was assuming include guards (#pragma once), I forgot write them in the example. That's why it wouldn't compile, because it sees it's already been included and doesn't include them again. I'll edit the question to include #pragma once, that's what I meant.

@NateEldredge Oh right, there's that too.

Include guards (standard) or #pragma once (non-standard but widely supported in some manner) will typically resolve concerns due to repeated/recursive inclusion of headers.     They don't resolve recursive dependencies of types, such as yours (in which both struct types include an instance of each other, which will never compile, regardless of how you organise your source or header files).

Changing the location of a #include can change the meaning of the contents of the .h file, e.g. if the .h file contains preprocessor macros that have been defined differently at different locations in the referencing file.  So allowing the preprocessor to implicitly move the #include lines around would be quite risky.

You need a better [mre]. Currently the types cannot possibly compile even within a single TU. Ask yourself what the size of Foo is and then the issue become evident (In this case you may argue it is trivially zero, but in any non-trivial case you have a struct of infinite size).

You have a bigger issue, you have two types recursively dependent on each other that will prevent you from being  able to compile at all (headers or not).  You should break that dependency first (redesign).  Eg. by making the member a pointer  or reference in  one of the classes and then using a foward declararion or putting the "shared type" in a separate header file (this will also break the circular file dependency)

@PepijnKramer Yes, I realise that now, I mean.. ignoring that. I think I realise now that my idea doesn't make sense because assuming you can see that Bar header should be moved higher, then Bar doesn't have the definition of Foo, and you'd need to move the Foo header higher, and so on forever.

A different solution to the problem, instead of changing the language in the way you've suggested, is to change the language such that it does two passes such that forward declarations are unnecessary.  Or modules, such that header files are unnecessary.

@Eljay Modules actually makes it more strict because two modules can use things from each other, whereas two ordinary translation units can.

so the end result is: Bar is not defined at the line struct Foo { Bar bar;}, so the code is invalid.

No, circular includes of header files does not cause any problems when this is protected by include guards like #pragma once.
The include guards make sure that you can include FooHeader.h and BarHeader.h as often and in any order you like, including any recursions.
Edit: As pointed out by a comment, circular includes can cause problems, see bottom section.
Circular includes can and probably should be omitted but that has nothing to do with compile errors but more with clean code and fewer include dependencies (how much do you have to recompile when you change a single header file).
Your example with Foo and Bar cannot work, no matter if you put it into one or two header files.
Besides of the definition problem, the size of the structures would be infinitly large.
At least one of the two type definitions requires to use a pointer or reference to a forward declaration to resolve the circular dependency.
This forward declaration also helps to get rid of the circular include as one of the two includes is no longer needed.
The pointer with the option to be a nullptr is also one way to stop the infitive instance recursion.
Something like this:
FooHeader.h
#pragma once
#include "BarHeader.h"

struct Foo { struct Bar bar; };

BarHeader.h
#pragma once
// no include needed
struct Foo; // forward declaration which is sufficient for pointers

struct Bar { struct Foo* pFoo; };

Edit: Circular includes can cause problems when the inner header tries to access a symbol which is not yet defined on the outer header.
The following non-recursive type example should cause such issues:
FooHeader.h
#pragma once
#include "BarHeader.h"

struct Foo { struct Bar2 bar; };

BarHeader.h
#pragma once
#include "FooHeader.h"

struct Bar { struct Foo foo; };
struct Bar2 { int i; };

Every header on its own looks fine but the definitions cannot be fully resolved.
When you include FooHeader.h, then struct Foo foo in BarHeader.h cannot be resolved.
When you include BarHeader.h, then struct Bar2 bar in FooHeader.h cannot be resolved.
The definitions would work when they are put in the order

Bar2
Foo
Bar


Yes, thank you, that was a mistake including them into each other.

Circular includes often cause errors, even if properly guarded, because the names defined by the outer header won't be seen until after processing the inner header. The inner header pulled in the outer header because it needed those names, but they aren't there. Forward references, as in your final example, are often the answer, but that means rewriting the headers to fix the errors that the circular include caused.

@PeteBecker: Thanks, for the explanation, the inner header can fail to find symbols on the outer as they are not yet defined and the inner-to-outer include is omitted by the include guard. I did not encounter this myself yet but it makes sense. I will adopt my answer.

#include "BarHeader.h"

int main() { }

becomes
// #include "BarHeader.h"
#pragma once // BarHeader
#include "FooHeader.h"
struct Bar { Foo foo; };

int main() { }

Then we expand the #include directive
// #include "BarHeader.h"
#pragma once // BarHeader
// #include "FooHeader.h"
#pragma once // FooHeader
#include "BarHeader.h"

struct Foo { Bar bar;};
struct Bar { Foo foo; };

int main() { }

now we expand #include "BarHeader.h" - this does nothing, because #pragma once "BarHeader.h" has already been evaluated, and we included 'BarHeader.h".
// #include "BarHeader.h"
#pragma once // BarHeader
// #include "FooHeader.h"
#pragma once // FooHeader
// #include "BarHeader.h"

struct Foo { Bar bar;};
struct Bar { Foo foo; };

int main() { }

and we get an error.
Your rule, "moving it to the earliest spot", makes no sense - we are already party way through BarHeader.h when we run into another BarHeader.h include.  You can't "rewind" it.
The techniques to deal with it are easy to understand.
What more, your specific example isn't solvable by any header order.  You cannot have class A inside class B, because classes in C++ are actual instances of the class not references to the class (as in C#/Java/etc).
The pre-declaration rules are actually there to help avoid circular structure definitions.

Right, two objects can't include each other. Ignoring that part of it I don't get what you mean by you can't "rewind it", but another problem I see with my whole idea is that even if you can move the header (ie., the definition of Bar) up higher, then Bar wouldn't have the definition of Foo. Right? I guess the only solution is to do two passes, which is I guess what the linker is, the second pass, and is why you can have two things use each other if you let the linker do it. Interestingly this is no longer possible with modules.

@Zebrafish Ignoring the core conflict problem?  If they don't include each other, then the code compiles without problem.  If they include pointers to each other, then you need to forward declare the types instead of including...  If the implementation of one uses the interface of the other, no problem either, include after interface but before implementation.

The thing is though that, despite what everyone says about two modules/classes needing each other, that it's a "code smell" or outright wrong, if you do need to do it you're forced to split it into as you said, interface and implementation. In the case of using new c++ modules you don't even have the option anymore. I found myself in a situation where I had "Logger" which required the "FileSystem" to write to files, and "FileSystem" which needed Logger to log stuff, and I don't know why that's wrong from a design point of view simply because the two rely on each other.

@ZebraFish  Do you know what the difference is between a "definition" and a "declaration" in C++?  If you don't then look it up.   Because, if you don't understand the difference (and relationship) between a definition and a declaration, you're doomed to never understanding why mutual dependency of definitions is wrong, but dependencies on declarations is okay.

@Peter "mutual dependency of definitions is wrong" - You mean in header files, not in translation units, right?

@Zebrafish It doesn't matter. Mutual dependency of definitions (meaning that each class needs to rely on the definition of the other class, not just declaration, in order to get itself defined) is always wrong.

@Zebrafish   I mean in general.   In your case, there is a mutual dependency between the definitions of the struct types Foo and Bar (both having a member that is an instance of the other).   That is a diagnosable error, regardless of whether those definitions are in a header file, in separate header files that include each other, or translation units.

@WeijunZhou No, it's not wrong, Translation Unit 1 has a struct Foo that requires the definition of struct Bar and Translation Unit 2 has a struct Bar that requires the definition of struct Foo. Not wrong at all.

We are talking about definitions of the classes themselves. Definition of class member functions is another matter. Once again, this has nothing to do with TUs whatsoever.

@WeijunZhou It still doesn't, the statements that you two have made seem plainly false. Foo in Translation Unit 1 can rely on a static inline int from another class, or a function definition, and in Translation Unit 2 the same can be done from Bar requiring the definitions inside Foo, whether function definitions or variables or anything. It's not an error. It's just false. The reason why there's the problem with headers including each is because of the failure of putting the right stuff before the other stuff, because the compiler reads from top to bottom and it hasn't seen it yet.

@Zebrafish No, you can't. If the definition class Foo{...}; requires a complete type Bar(whether you are using a typedef, a static member, or whatever from it), and the definition class Bar{...}; requires a complete type Foo, your program cannot be expressed in C++. This really is fundamental to C++ and is not related to header inclusions.

@Zebrafish If a Foo contains a Bar, and a Bar contains a Foo, then you have objects that contain themselves, which is absurd. You can solve the problem making Foo contain a pointer to a Bar, and vice versa. This works, because the pointer always has a fixed size, regardless of the size of the pointed-to element. Which is why a struct can even contain a pointer to itself. But your example doesn't use pointers.

@FabiosaysReinstateMonica Yeah that part is absurd, I mean leaving that aside. Like maybe it should have been call a function from Bar or something.

@WeijunZhou Ah yes, within the class definition yes.

@Zebrafish Now that we have come to agreement, I suggest you clarify your question by showing something that you can achieve using a single TU, but when you try to separate the different classes from that TU to multiple TUs, you come across issues due to header inclusion. That way we can have a better MRE as I have already commented on the question. Of course your edit should not invalidate existing answers.
